# how to change vm DNS name and ip addresses in vpshere client

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I've created a VM in vsphere client. There is an IP allocated for this VM. How do I add the IP address and DNS name to it via vsphere client.

Today is the first day I'm using vsphere (!)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The IP configuration of virtual machines depends on the guest OS - vSphere does not have direct control over this - you just use the Ethernet adapter settings (if you run Windows in the VM) or `ifconfig` (for Linux).

The IP Address and DNS fields are populated if you install VMware Tools - this is sofware that runs in the guest OS of your virtual machine and provides tighter integration with the virtual infrastructure. For example after installing VMware Tools you no longer need to press Ctrl+Alt to release the mouse cursor from inside the VM Console.